# If $x$ is a $\chi^2_{N-n}$ RV. what is $x/N$ as N goes to infinity

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics

We know that if we have $N-n$ gaussian iid RVs $\{e_i\}$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$, the RV $x = \sum e_i^2$ is $\chi^2$ distributed with $N-n$ degrees of freedom. We have $N$ larger than $n$.

I do not see why the Law of Large Numbers implies that

$\frac{x}{N} \to 1$ in probability as $N \to \infty$

I know that $\frac{\sum{e_i}}{N-n} \to 0$ in  as $N \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

If $e_1,\ldots,e_N$ are i.i.d. with mean $0$ and variance $1$, then $e_1^2,\ldots,e_N^2$ are i.i.d. with mean $1$, so, by the law of large numbers,
$\frac1N\sum\limits_{i=1}^Ne_i^2\to1$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: The summation is from $i=1$ to $N-n$. Will this affect the result?

Comment: The result will be the same. If $x_N\to1$ as $N\to\infty$, then $x_{N-n}\to1$ as $N\to\infty$, for any constant $n$.